# Can't get the current wifi connection using win32com.client in python

Tags: python, proxy, wmi, win32com

I'm trying to make a python script that automatically switch on and off the manual proxy setup in windows 10 (check the image) based on the name of the current network, I'm doing this because a wifi network on my school require a proxy to work and I'm tired of switching it on and off manually and sometimes forgetting to switching it on and waste time trying to understand what's wrong...
[screenshot of the settings that I want to controle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fDBFb.png)
So here is the code
`

```
import win32com.client
import time

# Replace this with the name of the WiFi network that you want
# the script to enable the proxy for
TARGET_NETWORK_NAME = "ENSIAS-STUDENT"

# Replace this with the address and port of the proxy server
# that you want to use when connected to the target network
PROXY_SERVER_ADDRESS = "10.23.201.11"
PROXY_SERVER_PORT = 3128


def set_proxy(enabled: bool):
    """Enable or disable the manual proxy setup in Windows 10."""
    # Connect to the Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI) service
    wmi = win32com.client.GetObject("winmgmts:")

    # Get the current WiFi connection
    wifi_connection = wmi.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_NetworkAdapter WHERE NetConnectionID LIKE 'Wi-Fi'")[0]

    # Get the settings of the current WiFi connection
    settings = wifi_connection.Setting

    # Set the proxy settings of the WiFi connection based on the
    # enabled flag
    settings.IPX.EnableIPSec = False
    settings.IPX.EnableIPsecNATTraversal = False
    settings.IPX.EnableL2TPOverIPSec = False
    settings.IPX.AutoConfigurationEnabled = not enabled
    settings.IPX.ProxyServer = PROXY_SERVER_ADDRESS if enabled else ""
    settings.IPX.ProxyPort = PROXY_SERVER_PORT if enabled else 0
    settings.IPX.EnableProxy = enabled
    settings.Put_()


# Continuously check the name of the currently connected WiFi network
# and enable or disable the proxy accordingly
while True:
    # Connect to the Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI) service
    wmi = win32com.client.GetObject("winmgmts:")

    # Get the current WiFi connection
    wifi_connection = wmi.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_NetworkAdapter WHERE NetConnectionID LIKE 'Wi-Fi'")[0]

    # Get the name of the network that the WiFi connection is currently connected to
    network_name = wifi_connection.NetConnectionID

    # Check if the WiFi connection is connected to the target network
    if network_name == TARGET_NETWORK_NAME:
        # Enable the manual proxy setup
        set_proxy(True)
    else:
        # Disable the manual proxy setup
        set_proxy(False)

    # Sleep for 1 second before checking the network again
    time.sleep(1)
```

When I run it it says:
AttributeError: .Setting
after debugging I found that

```
    wifi_connection = wmi.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_NetworkAdapter WHERE NetConnectionID LIKE 'Wi-Fi'")[0]
```

this line of code returns `<COMObject <unknown>>` which I believe is wrong and should return something else.
I checked the WMI service and it's running, I tried modifying the query and it always give the samething.

I tried another approach which is using `netsh winhttp set proxy proxy-server=http://myproxy:8080` and it says that the proxy server is updated but the network doesn't work.
Can someone help please?

Comment: shot in the dark here - are you running all these as Administrator on your PC?

Comment: Yes I run it as administrator

Comment: You may have some out of date WMI code (the error is telling you that your Win32_NetworkAdapter object does not have a property called `Setting`, and indeed it does not: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-networkadapter. After your `netsh` call, run `netsh winhttp show proxy`. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc731131(v=ws.10) The documentation for `set proxy` suggests you might need some quotation marks around your strings.